# Rails: How to Cache Votes with thumbs_up gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have a the thumbs_up gem connected with a user and a micropost and I want to create a column to the micropost table to count the amount of votes the micropost has.

I am not sure how to do this because the thumbs_up gem on github does not explain how to cache the votes in a different model.

I am doing this so I can sort the microposts through the amounts of votes.

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought about using a counter cache in the micropost table?  Here's a link if counter cache operations are new for you: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache.html#method-i-update_counters

Comment: The thing is I am using the thumbs_up gem and I am unsure how to connect the vote_up column to the micropost so the micropost would have a column to save the vote_ups that are stored in the thumbs_up table...Here is the gem if you are unfamiliar https://github.com/brady8/thumbs_up